# Delete a user from frontend

Tags: users, login, user-access, customization

I'm developing a user management table, in which an user (I've already set restriction for for some specific roles) can create/edit or delete a user. How can I delete a user by clicking on delete link or button, I have stored the id in a variable.

Comment: There'll need to be a request to the server, some code to delete the user, and some checks to verify that the user is capable of doing this. Right now your problem is too large on its own to solve as a single thing, so break it down into sub-problems and tackle each individual part. I suspect the fundamental missing piece you're missing is either AJAX, or how to do stuff only on URL parameters, aka the form handler problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the user id, you could create a link similar to https://example.com/wp-admin/users.php?action=delete&user=2 , where the value of the user is the user ID.

You can also hook into a function in the `users.php` file. It's a core file, so you don't want to change it. But you can use the functions therein to properly delete the user.

Comment: This is not working in my case, I'm developing a membership panel, so the head of a group can delete any user under him. I'm able to display the members in a table but can't delete them.
Is there any way to call `wp_delete_user()` on click of anchor tag or button?

Comment: Your template that displays the list of users can have a button (in a form block) that sets a POST variable. Then your template (when the page is submitted) would check the POST variable and call functions based on the POST variable's value. The 'action' of the form(s) on the page would be set to "" (itself). At the top of the template, you'd check for the Submit action of the form, then do something based on that form's POST values.